# Google authentication integration in my own android app

Tags: android, oauth

I have an android application. I need to login with Google (gmail) account in my android application.

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/). But when run my application I got this error:

```
OAuthRequestTokenTask(1100): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 400 (Bad Request) exceptions.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you authorized your token from a browser?

Comment: why dont you use google play service? https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/authentication

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by 'login with Google account in my android application'? Are you trying to use a particular Google service?